# API для распознавания штрих-кодов бутылок для android studio

Tags: java, android

Как реализовать скан штрих-кода и понимание объема товара которому принадлежит этот штрих-код в случае с бутылкой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно для Android сейчас оптимальным вариантом является [Barcode API](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview). Это библиотека от гугла, работает более стабильно, чем сторонние. Также для этой библиотеки есть [хорошие уроки](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bar-codes/#0) по созданию с нуля приложения для распознавания штрихкодов.